# Relation between snmp trap object and trap itslef

Tags: networking, snmp, snmp-trap

I am new to SNMP, I was looking at some mib files and how traps are defined. Seems like they go like this:

```
dartTrapObjects        OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {dart 2}
dartTraps            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {dart 3}

temp OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX        Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS    read-write
    STATUS        current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Description for an integer"
    ::= {dartTrapObjects 1}

overheat NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS
    {
        temp
    }
    STATUS    current
    DESCRIPTION
        "overheat trap"
    ::= {dartTraps 1}
```

what is object *temp* doing here? how is it related to the trap? if the agent sends the trap (overheat) what is the point of variable temp in that scenario?

Comment: Normally you won't send an empty notification (`overheat`) but also some parameters like temperature. That's where an extra object (or objects) like `temp` can be useful. Whoever receives the notification can then respond to not only overheat, but also learn how badly the situation was.

Comment: that makes sense, but how do you handle it on agent side?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722101/how-to-send-specific-trap-in-lwip

Comment: also does that mean when trap occurs, the manager also requests to read the variable temp?

Comment: On agent side? You merely send out the TRAP message with TRAP OID (`overheat`) and the object(s) (`temp`), so everything comes in a single packet. The manager on the other side parses the message to learn the details, but it won't send extra GET requests as the object(s) is already in the TRAP message.

Comment: Thanks! Let's say we want to send a trap message on the agent side (which is an embedded device) when overheating occurs. The first solution that comes to my mind is to just have a loop that reads the temp and send a trap if the temp is over a threshold. Does that make sense? Is that the best solution?

Comment: That makes some sense, but your algorithm is too simple to be useful (it might send floods of TRAP messages in a short period of time). My advice is that you build a quick prototype and test it out. Hire an experienced consultant and that can save you lots of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224227/discussion-between-notalphazero-and-lex-li).